# React Native stack navigator has a delay between screen transitions

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

For some reason, switching screens with a Stack navigator causes this lag between the transition and I'm not sure why.
[Click to see the lagging transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYX6X.gif)

The code snippet looks something like this:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Main"
          component={MainContainer}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={LoginScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

In the gif I'm moving from the LoginScreen component to the MainContainer component

I've tried using Stack navigator on a separate empty project and it still had the same problem.

Comment: Not particularly. I've just made each screen with a flex: 1 and a white background. Seems otherwise, the screens are transparent.